# Get dynamically generated column names from result of sql query

Tags: mysql, sql, jsp, jpa, entitymanager

I'm executing stored procedure with jpa entity manager as below.

```
List coll = entityManager.getEntityManager()
                    .createNativeQuery("CALL CollectionByCenter()")
                    .getResultList();
```

This stored procedure creates column names depending on another table. Here is the [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!8/523eb/9) for the query in my stored procedure.

I need to display output of this query on JSP page. I'm using JSTL for display data on jsp. But i need to know column names to display data.

How can i do this ? How can i get all column names with their values ?

Comment: See extract(), but this is generally considered really bad practice. It's your database. You should know the column names in advance.

Comment: @Strawberry Column names are generate dynamically. See this [link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!8/523eb/9). then you can understand how it's work.